# Getting max value before given date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am pretty new to using MS SQL 2012 and I am trying to create a query that will:

1. Report the order id, the order date and the employee id that processed the order
2. report the maximum shipping cost among the orders processed by the same employee prior to that order

This is the code that I've come up with, but it returns the freight of the particular order date. Whereas I am trying to get the maximum freight from all the orders before the particular order.

```
select o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate, t2.maxfreight
from orders o
inner join
(
    select employeeid, orderdate, max(freight) as maxfreight
    from orders
    group by EmployeeID, OrderDate
) t2
on o.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
inner join
(
    select employeeid, max(orderdate) as mostRecentOrderDate
    from Orders
    group by EmployeeID
) t3
on t2.EmployeeID = t3.EmployeeID
where o.freight = t2.maxfreight and t2.orderdate < t3.mostRecentOrderDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one is to read the order:

```
select o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate
from   orders o
where  o.orderid = @ParticularOrder;
```

That gives you everything you need to go out and get the previous orders from the same employee and join each one to the row you get from above.

```
select  o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate, o2.freight
from    orders o
join    orders o2
    on  o2.employeeid = o.employeeid
    and o2.orderdate < o.orderdate
where   o.orderid = @ParticularOrder;
```

Now you have a whole bunch of rows with the first three values the same and the fourth is the freight cost of each previous order. So just group by the first three fields and select the maximum of the previous orders.

```
select  o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate, max( o2.freight ) as maxfreight
from    orders o
join    orders o2
    on  o2.employeeid = o.employeeid
    and o2.orderdate < o.orderdate
where   o.orderid = @ParticularOrder
group by o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate;
```

Done. Build your query in stages and many times it will turn out to be much simpler than you at first thought.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you are using t3. From the question it doesn't sound like the employee's most recent order date is relevant at all, unless I am misunderstanding (which is absolutely possible).

I believe the issue lies in t2. You are grouping by orderdate, which will return the max freight for that date and employeeid, as you describe. You need to calculate a maximum total from all orders that occurred before the date that the order occurred on, for that employee, for every row you are returning.

It probably makes more sense to use a subquery for this.

```
SELECT o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate, m.maxfreight
FROM 
    orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT max(freight) as maxfreight 
    FROM orders AS f
    WHERE f.orderdate <= o.orderdate AND f.employeeid = o.employeeid
) AS m
```

Hoping this is syntactically correct as I'm not in front of SSMS right now. I also included a left outer join as your previous query with an inner join would have excluded any rows where an employee had no previous orders (i.e. first order ever).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think the logic you are using is correct!
It is almost syntactically correct, I am however getting a "Incorrect syntax near 'm'." do I need to make an on argument after the "m"?

Comment: Try this:   SELECT o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate, m.maxfreight
FROM 
    orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT max(freight)  as maxfreight , f.employeeid
    FROM orders AS f 
    WHERE f.orderdate <= o.orderdate AND f.employeeid = o.employeeid GROUP BY f.employeeid
) AS m ON m.employeeid = o.employeeid

Comment: If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll figure it out when I have access to ssms tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a correlated subquery or `apply`.  Here is one way:

```
select o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate, t2.maxfreight
from orders o outer apply
     (select max(freight) as maxfreight
      from orders o2
      where o2.employeeid = o.employeid and
            o2.orderdate < o.orderdate
     ) t2;
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can also do this with a cumulative maximum:

```
select o.employeeid, o.orderid, o.orderdate,
       max(freight) over (partition by employeeid
                          order by o.orderdate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                         ) as maxfreight
from orders o;
```